# How to use custom type with WCF data service and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, wcf-data-services

I've created a WCF Data Service with a base class of my EF model.

I wanted to return a custom type (one that isn't in my EF model), but I get the error:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help 
page for constructing valid requests to the service.
```

My custom class looks like:

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
     public string CustomProp { get; set; }
     public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found to do this with WCF **Data** Services is to pass a json string as a parameter and then deserialize it into the custom class.

Like so:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public bool ConfigurationChanged(string jsonStr)
{
    try
    {
        MyObject obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonStr);

        // ... do something with MyObject
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your return object as a data contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyCustomClass
{
     [DataMember]
     public string CustomProp { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

See also: [How to accept JSON in a WCF DataService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917380/how-to-accept-json-in-a-wcf-dataservice/6918694#6918694)

Linked is how to set up a receiving service, returning the values you just change the return types on your methods.

Comment: This works with regular WCF Services but not with Entity Framework